# I want to make the navigation bar sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-position

I want to make this navbar sticky, after applying the below css it behaves like sticky for one page but when I scroll more it goes up and don't behave like sticky. Please help me to fix this.

Sticky navbar works scrolling till header content but after scrolling beyond header it goes up and hide.

```css
    #header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background-image: url(/img/pp-desktop.png);
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }

    .container {
      padding: 10px 10%;
    }

    .logo {
      width: 80px;
    }

    nav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
/* From here I added CSS for sticky behaviour....*/
      align-self: flex-start;
      position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 10px 20px;
    }


Sticky navbar works scrolling till header content but after scrolling beyond header it goes up and hide.
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">

        <nav>
            <img src="/img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="" />
            <ul id="sidemenu">
                <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-square-xmark" onclick="closeMenu()"></i>
            </ul>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" onclick="openMenu()"></i>
        </nav>

        <div class="header-text">
            <p>Software Developer</p>
            <h1>Hi, I am <span>xyz</span> </br> from India</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>



<div id="about">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="about-col-1">
                <img src="/img/me.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="about-col-2">
                <h1 class="sub-title">About Me</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam
                    aspernatur earum tempora, adipisci consequatur ea temporibus quidem animi excepturi
                    est assumenda, eius debitis et deleniti accusamus reprehenderit deserunt labore!
                    Repellendus magnam cumque commodi corporis cum vel architecto sed. Quam laudantium
                    possimus doloribus cumque voluptatum placeat vero aut non libero a?</p>
                <div class="tab-titles">
                    <p class="tab-links active-link" onclick="opentab('skills')">Skills</p>
                    <p class="tab-links" onclick="opentab('experience')">Experience</p>
                    <p class="tab-links" onclick="opentab('education')">Education</p>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-contents active-tab" id="skills">
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Software Dev</span></br>Fullstack Developer</li>
                        <li><span>Software Dev</span></br>Fullstack Developer</li>
                        <li><span>Software Dev</span></br>Fullstack Developer</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-contents" id="experience">
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>2021 - 2022</span></br>Fullstack Developer</li>
                        <li><span>2021 - 2022</span></br>Fullstack Developer</li>
                        <li><span>2020 - 2021</span></br>Fullstack Developer</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-contents" id="education">
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>2021 - 2022</span></br>Fullstack Developer</li>
                        <li><span>2021 - 2022</span></br>Fullstack Developer</li>
                        <li><span>2020 - 2021</span></br>Fullstack Developer</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you might be confused between the use case of `sticky` and `fixed`.

- `fixed` position content never leaves the viewport and it is always visible
- `sticky` position context leaves the viewport when the parent is scrolled out of the viewport.

Hence, `.header` is scrolled out of view and the nav goes away with it.

In your case:

```
nav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-self: flex-start;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

This should fix the issue. If you want multiple headers for each container, you may use `sticky`.
I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for answering, this worked but it shrinked the navbar.

Comment: You might have to manipulate the height and width since there is no parent element for the nav to inherit height and width from.

Comment: do adding nav inside a parent container resolve this issue.

Comment: You can just give it a `height` and `width` property in `px` or `%`. That will fix it

Answer (score 0):

so you want to create a `sticky` or `fixed` navbar, Ok it's not that much hard. I will give you an example with the source code . Let's try the below code.

Source Code : [Sticky Navbar](https://jsfeed.io/blog/7865og824s/how-to-create-sticky-navbar)

Example:
1] Use HTML

```
 <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

2] Use Css

```
    nav {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #333;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    nav ul li {
      margin: 0 10px;
    }
    
    nav ul li a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }

   .sticky + .content {
      padding-top: 60px;
   }
```

3] Use JavaScript

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.querySelector("nav");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

This will help you to create sticky navbar.